# Angular services issue

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-service

I need some help to understand what is wrong in the following angular service code.

EDIT:
I have few controllers in different js files that use CRUD API like

```
$http.get('/api/sites/' + service.siteID)
```

or simply need variables directive like

```
templateUrl: '../../' + service.template + ' + '.html'
```

So I create a service to share those variables between all js file instead of making api call in each file.

Here is the service

```
app.service('SharedData', function($http) {

$http.get('config.json') 
    .success (function(data) {  
        var siteID = data._id;
        console.log(siteID); // return 553e2d15f91e4bd75d000008

         $http.get('/api/sites/' + siteID)
            .success(function(site) {
                var template = site.template;
                console.log(template); // return myTemplate
            })
            .error(function(data) {
                console.log('Error: ' + data);
            })
    })
    .error(function(data) {
        console.log('Error: ' + data);
    })

service = {
    siteID :    siteID, // return undefined instead of 553e2d15f91e4bd75d000008
    template :  template // return undefined instead of myTemplate                      
    };

return service;
})
```

I just want to make a precision. If I write my service like below, it works fine, I mean the value are well passed in all controllers and directives

```
app.service('SharedData', function() {
service = {
    siteID : '553e2d15f91e4bd75d000008',
    pageID : '553e2d15f91e4bd75d000009',
    template : 'template1',
    layout : 'home'
    };

return service;
})
```

Many Thanks

**EDIT**

I have change the service as follow

```
app.factory('SharedData', function($http) {
service = {};
$http.get('config.json') 
    .success (function(data) {  
        service.siteId = data._id; 
        //console.log(service.siteId);

        $http.get('/api/sites/' + service.siteId)
            .success(function(site) {
                service.template = site.template;
                //console.log(service.template);
            })
    })
service.pageID = '553e2d15f91e4bd75d000009';
service.layout = 'home'
return service
})
```

In the controller console.log(service) return an object with all value :

```
layout: "home"
pageID: "553e2d15f91e4bd75d000009"
siteId: "553e2d15f91e4bd75d000008"
template: "template1"

console.log('Layout is ' + service.layout); // return home
console.log('PageID is ' + service.pageID); // return 553e2d15f91e4bd75d000009
```

but

```
console.log('siteID is ' + service.siteId); // return undefined  !!!!!
console.log('template is ' + service.template); // return undefined !!!!!
```

DO NOT UNDERSTAND PLEASE HELP

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I get this help from Google Group

*"You are getting your information asynchronous. Simply said, the information is not yet available on the moment you are logging them out. Only when the $http calls are 'done'  you will have the information available in your controller.
In the debugger screen, service is an 'live' object, so it gets updated. the data is not an object (at that point) and is logged as such.
Have a look at the $q service on how promises work in angular."*

Then here is how to fix the issue with $q

```
service = {};
    app.service('GetSiteID', function ($http) {
        return $http.get('config.json') 
        .then (function(response) { 
            service.siteID = response.data._id
            return service.siteID
   });
})  
app.service('GetTemplateAndPages', function (GetSiteID, $http, $q) {
    return GetSiteID
        .then(function(id) {
        return $http.get('/api/sites/' + id)
            .then (function(response) {
                var data = response.data;
                service.template = response.data.template;
                service.pages = response.data.pages;
                return service.template;
                return service.pages
       })
    })
})  
app.service('SharedData', function (GetSiteID, GetTemplateAndPages, $q) {
    return $q.all([GetSiteID, GetTemplateAndPages]) 
        .then (function(response) {
         return service
    })
})
```

then use it in controller like

```
app.controller('pagesController', function(SharedData, $scope, $http) {
    SharedData.then(function(service) {
      console.log(service);
      console.log('Site ID is ' + service.siteID); 
      console.log('Template is ' + service.template);
      console.log('Pages are ' + service.pages);
   })
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Your siteID variable is referenced outside of the $http.get method's scope.

Define siteID above the function like so:

```
app.service('SharedData', function($http) {
var siteID = '';
$http.get('config.json') 
    .success (function(data) {  
        siteID = data._id;
        console.log(siteID); // return 553e2d15f91e4bd75d000008

         $http.get('/api/sites/' + siteID)
            .success(function(site) {
                var template = site.template;
                console.log(template); // return myTemplate
            })
            .error(function(data) {
                console.log('Error: ' + data);
            })
    })
    .error(function(data) {
        console.log('Error: ' + data);
    })

service = {
    siteID :    siteID, // return undefined
    template :  template,                       
    };

return service;
})
```

Comment: I think it's a bit messy to do it this way... You need 3 declarations this way, two of which only act as a passthrough to the final service object.

Comment: Yes, I'd agree. Though the issue OP has is essentially not understanding object scope.

Answer (score 1):

You are not constructing objects properly.  You need to define the object first, then assign values to the objects properties:

```
app.service('SharedData', function($http) {

var service = {
    siteID :    '', // return undefined
    template :  '',                       
    };

$http.get('config.json') 
    .success (function(data) {  
        service.siteID = data._id;
        console.log(siteID); // return 553e2d15f91e4bd75d000008

         $http.get('/api/sites/' + siteID)
            .success(function(site) {
                service.template = site.template;
                console.log(template); // return myTemplate
                return service;
            })
            .error(function(data) {
                console.log('Error: ' + data);
            })
    })
    .error(function(data) {
        console.log('Error: ' + data);
    })



})
```

I am not entirely sure you are understanding correctly how you should make use of the service in your controllers, so here is a little demo I set up:

[Services Demo](http://plnkr.co/edit/mlJJACRnMexWmXPrLScG?p=preview)

Comment: I get service is not defined!

Comment: yea try moving `return service` inside your inner success

Comment: see above.  You don't want it returning until after your ajax call finishes.

Comment: It seems ok but know I am not able to use service.siteID or service.template in controllers for example I get mydomain:3000//layouts/home.html where I should get mydomain:3000/templateValue/layouts/home.html

Comment: BTW I should remove var in var service otherwise I get service is undefined and replace siteID = {} by siteID = ''

Comment: check my updated answer...Make sure you are accessing the data that the service is returning correctly also..check the demo.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/76553/discussion-between-artefact-and-tpie).